# Equal or : Comparison Operators for string boolean

Tags: .net, vb.net

Let's say i have text box , i want to check the input is not Character "a" or "b" and not integer as well.

**I've tried**

```
dim intCheck as Integer
if (not textbox1.text = "a" or "b" or intCheck) then
#mycode
End if
```

I Don't want to add multi Else If because this is just a sample i have alot of code may overwrite and became spaghetti code

Comment: it's pretty easy in python or php to do that but i'm vb newbie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want one `If` statement, you may use something like this:

```
Dim value As String = TextBox1.Text
If value <> "a" AndAlso value <> "b" AndAlso Not Integer.TryParse(value, Nothing) Then
    ' Do something
End If
```

See: [Integer.TryParse documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?System_Int32_TryParse_System_String_System_Int32__).

This works well because you only have two values ("a" and "b") to check against. If you want to check against more values, you may find the [`String.Contains()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.contains) or [`IEnumerable.Contains()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.contains) methods helpful:

```
' Check if value is not "a" or "b" or "c" or d".
If Not "abcd".Contains(value) Then ' Do something.

' Check if value is not "a" or "b" or "test".
If Not { "a", "b", "test" }.Contains(value) Then ' Do something.
```

Comment: very helpful , but is there's something similar to AndAlso but for "OR"

Comment: @hewman Yes, it's called `OrElse`. You can find all operators [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/operators-and-expressions/).

Comment: i have tried OrElse instead of first AndAlso , in your first example , and left second AndAlso because i need to check it's not int + it's not b "OR" a

Comment: didn't work with me gives me all true even if it has a or b @ICloneable

Comment: You need to use the correct logic. If I understand you correctly, you want to make sure that the input is not and int _and_ it's not the letter "a" _and_ it's also not the letter "b". Correct? If so, then you should be using `AndAlso` as I suggested and not `OrElse`. Otherwise, please explain exactly what values should _Not_ be accepted.

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Te5EqR @ICloneable can you check this fiddle

Comment: @hewman First of all, when you use both AND and OR, you must use parenthesis. However, that won't even help you here. I still have no idea what values should not be accepted. Can you please mention that? When you say "it shouldn't be a or b", it actually means "it shouldn't be a _**AND**_ it also shouldn't be b", right? Or do you mean something else?